# Can I configure the glow color of the alt-tab switcher?

Tags: unity

I'm using Unity 3D.

When switching windows using <kbd>alt</kbd>+<kbd>Tab</kbd>, the selected windows get a white backlight, which is not very readable.

Can I change this behavior somehow? E.g. Zoom in the selected icon to make it bigger?
I don't see any options in `ccsm` for this.
Maybe there is any better alternative for the default window switcher?

Comment: You can change all the other task background color to transparent.
http://askubuntu.com/questions/123670/how-i-turn-off-backlight-around-switcher-icons

Answer (score 3):

I don't know of any way to change the colour of the alt+tab switcher in Unity, but you can use an alternative in Compiz. Let us look at the alternatives:

### Before we start:

**Create a nautilus script to reload Unity when ever it crashes:**

- Create a text file called "unityreloader" (no file extension).
- Place this text in it:

> ```
>  #!/bin/sh
>  unity
> ```

- Mark the file as executable and place it in ~/.gnome2/nautilus-scripts
- When ever you make a change in CCSM that causes Unity to exit, simply right click on the Desktop, choose scripts, and click `unityreloader`. This will restart Unity so you don't have to log out and back in.

Install the extra Compiz Plugins: [Compiz-Plugins-Extra](http://packages.ubuntu.com/compiz-plugins-extra) [image: Install compiz-plugins-extra].

### Shift-Switcher:

[image: Shift]
This plugin is not perfect, but it is rather aesthetically pleasing.
By default, it will have some minor conflicts, so you will need to change the keyboard shortcuts. Please not that any keyboard shortcut using <kbd>super</kbd> will probably cause problems or fail to work because Unity uses this for many actions.

### Ring-Switcher:

[image: Ring]
Similar to the Shift-Switcher, however by default it exits when you release the shortcut key.

### Scale:

[image: Scale]
If configured correctly, Scale can be used to show all windows on the workspace (or all workspaces).
[image]

### NB:

The following two caused Compiz to lock up on me when I enabled them (though they work after logging out and back in again) - use at your own risk:

### Application Switcher and Static Application Switcher:

The most basic of all, these two are similar to the default app switcher, but show text colours correctly.
[image]

Answer (score 1):

I answered a similar question here: [how to change Alt+Tab window highlight color in Unity 2D](https://askubuntu.com/questions/135538/how-to-change-alttab-window-highlight-color-in-unity-2d)

Requires some hacking, but answers the "how to change glow color" part of your question.