# How I turn off backlight around switcher icons

Tags: unity, 14.04, application-switcher

In the Launcher it is possible to switch off the backlight of the icons.

How can I reach the same effect for the switcher icons? I would like to pass from this:
[image: switcher with backlight]

to this (colored with GIMP):

[image: switcher without backlight]

I think it would be easier to identify the selected icon.

Comment: Because its so hard to identify which icon is selected I switched back to Unity 2D

Comment: Another problem of variable backgrounds is that if you have a terminal (black) and an editor (white) underneath, it is really hard to quickly tell what icon is selected. Example screenshot: http://i.stack.imgur.com/Lm90V.png

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can replace the background image for the launchers with a transparent one. In a terminal, run the following (this is for Ubuntu **12.04**, in **11.10** you'd change the path to say *4* instead of *5*. For ubuntu **14.04** see the comments  below):

1. Backup the original:

   ```
   sudo cp /usr/share/unity/5/launcher_icon_back_150.png{,.back}
   ```
2. Edit the file:

   ```
   gimp /usr/share/unity/5/launcher_icon_back_150.png
   ```
3. In GIMP, press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd> to select everything. Then <kbd>Del</kbd> to remove it. Hit <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>S</kbd> to save it as a new picture to, e.g., `/home/launcher_icon_back_150.png`, and finally press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Q</kbd> to quit.
4. Move the new image to the right place:

   ```
   sudo mv /home/launcher_icon_back_150.png /usr/share/unity/5/
   ```
5. Log out and back in.
6. If you want to go back, simply run:

   ```
   sudo mv /usr/share/unity/5/launcher_icon_back_150.png{.back,}
   ```

   and log out and back in again.

[image]

Comment: At 2013-10-23 (Ubuntu **13.10 Saucy**) the image file is stored in `/usr/share/unity/icons/launcher_icon_back_150.png` and the edited image must be "exported" with Shift+Ctrl+E

Comment: At 2014-05-13 (Ubuntu **14.04 Trusty LTS**) the image file is an `svg` file stored as `/usr/share/unity/icons/launcher_icon_back_150.svg`. The image can be edited with **inkscape**

Answer (score 0):

MyUnity's launcher tab has a backlights parameter to do what you wish.

Comment: it turns off the launcher backlights but not the switcher backlights