# Remove icon borders in Unity application switcher

Tags: unity, compiz, application-switcher

In Unity's application switcher (ALT-TAB), each icon has a colored border (see red arrow in screenshot below).

It is misleading, a bright icon has a bright border, making it look as if it were the currently selected icon.

Is there a way to disable this border?

[image]

*Note: I already applied the tip from [this different question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/123670/how-i-turn-off-backlight-around-switcher-icons).*

Comment: This 5+ year old unanswered question with no comments addresses Ubuntu 12.04 or older version which are all EOL. At the time it should have been submitted as a feature request but now it is too late as the Alt+Tab feature now uses different highlighting altogether (on my Ubuntu 16.04 anyway) and solves the problem. VTC as `not reproducible`.