# how to change Alt+Tab window highlight color in Unity 2D

Tags: compiz, themes, unity-2d, workspaces, colors

i have Ubuntu 12.04, and i run unity 2D (so i can run all of my monitors with xinerama).

a problem that i have is when i hit alt+tab, it highlights the new [active] window with a white border.  well, if the window i want is behind another window that has a lot of white (like a web browser that is opened to a page with a white background (i.e. 80% of the web)), i can't tell which window i've alt-tab'd to.

where can i change the color and thickness of the window when it has been highlighted via alt+tab?  i'd like a nice, thick orange or red background.

is this a CCSM thing?  or do i need to alter via the metacity files?

thanks in advance.

Comment: Tim reports a a similar desire with Unity 3D.

Answer (score 4):

Based on the answer found here:   [How I turn off backlight around switcher icons](https://askubuntu.com/questions/123670/how-i-turn-off-backlight-around-switcher-icons)

**Short Answer**

You need to edit the file /usr/share/unity/5/launcher_icon_glow_200.png. I used GIMPs Colors -> Map -> Color Exchange to edit the color to my liking.

**Long Answer (had inline images, but my rep is too low)**

I first used the referenced answer to delete the background PNG as described and then was able to locate the file(s) you want to edit. In my case, I found that just changing the glow was not enough.

First make a back up of the two files, launcher_icon_selected_back_150.png and launcher_icon_glow_200.png.

```
cd /usr/shar/unity/5
sudo cp launcher_icon_selected_back_150.png launcher_icon_selected_back_150.png.bak
sudo cp launcher_icon_glow_200.png launcher_icon_glow_200.png.bak
```

You can edit the two files however you like. To keep it simple, I edited just the background color:

sudo gimp launcher_icon_selected_back_150.png

I personally made the selected background darker. If some Gimp effect isn't working, make sure you change the color mode to RGB.

Here's what it looks like when I alt + tab looks now:

[image]

Comment: i just got to looking at this.  guess i wasn't specific enough with my question.  i'm looking to change the color/border around the actual windows of the program i am highlighting, not the icons within the launcher window.  say i got 10 terminal windows open, spread across 4 screens, plus google open on one.  if i am trying to alt+tab to the terminal window on the same screen as Google, i don't really know when i've landed on it.  the quick launcher window is just showing 10 terminal icons.  so i don't know which is which.  i want to change the color that outlines the actual terminal window.